# Uploading files in flash 10 on a facebook profile

Tags: flash, facebook

I am developing a facebook application which sits in an application tab.

The app is developed in flash and as such must use fb:swf to embed the swf.
Therefore it sets allowScriptAccess = never on the swf.

There are 3 things that I will need to do, and I am not sure if it will be possible.

1) Load external SWF files into the parent swf

2) Load dynamic XML from the server

3) Upload files to the server

I am using flash 10.

Does allowScriptAccess = never stop us from achieving any of these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about the Security restrictions in Facebook but setting allowScriptAccess = never should not change how you can communicate to the server. It just disallows communication with JavaScript.

To upload file see:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf6.html

Loading external SWF:
http://www.iheartactionscript.com/loading-an-external-swf-in-as3/

Load XML from Server:
http://theflashblog.com/?p=242

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought. There shouldn't be any other security restrictions, because facebook is just rendering an embed tag. There is no allowNetworking setting, so hopefully I will be fine. Just putting together a quick POC to test out.

Comment: All works a charm. Looking on google you would think that working with fb:swf is a complete nightmare, but all seems pretty straightforward to me if you understand the JS limitations.